# Binding Context for custom child view Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a view called **MainPage.xaml** that contains multiple lessonPickViews.

The **lessonPickView.xaml** only contains a label with the text binded to Title property for simplicity.

i am unable to bind the lessonPickView to the **lessonPickViewModel**.cs from within MainPage.cs.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"            
             x:Class="KanjiStudy.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KanjiStudy.View">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Label Margin="0,20,0,0" Text="Grade 1"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <StackLayout Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <local:LessonPickView x:Name="g1l1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView x:Name="g1l2" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView x:Name="g1l3" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView x:Name="g1l4" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Margin="0,20,0,0" Text="Grade 2"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                    <local:LessonPickView Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    </local:LessonPickView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,20" Padding="20,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="20,0,50,20" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Study" >
                </Button>
                <Button Margin="50,0,20,20" FontSize="Large" Text="Test" Clicked="Button_Clicked">
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.cs
If i moved the binding code below to the LessonPick.cs class then all objects get the their title property binded to the same string. But i need it in this class so i can pass different titles.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        LessonPickView g1l1V = LessonView_get("g1l1");
        LessonPickView g1l2V = LessonView_get("g1l2");
        LessonPickView g1l3V = LessonView_get("g1l3");
        LessonPickView g1l4V = LessonView_get("g1l4");

        LessonPickViewModel viewModel = new LessonPickViewModel();
        g1l1V.BindingContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.title = "Hello world";

    }


    private LessonPickView LessonView_get(String name_)
    {
        LessonPickView lessonView = this.FindByName<LessonPickView>(name_);

        return lessonView;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayAlert("Title","Hi world","Cancel");
    }
}
```

LessonPickView

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KanjiStudy.View.LessonPickView">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <Frame OutlineColor="Black">
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Frame>

      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

LessonPickViewModel

```
class LessonPickViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Title != value)
            {
                Title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are setting viewModel.title (lowercase) which is an internal field, not the public property that fires the PropertyChanged event

Comment: when using viewModel.Title it throws an error during runtime causing it to crash.

setting viewModel.title works when done within the LessonPickView.cs class but not within the MainPage.cs

Comment: Your setter is recursive

Comment: Got it working; needed to set binding context g1l1V.BindingContext = viewModel; after setting the title to "hello world"

Comment: if you would fix the problems with your VM the order of assignment wouldn't matter

Comment: what is wrong with the vm ?

Comment: as I pointed out before, your setter is recursive; that is why it crashes when you try to set Title.  "title = value;" (lower case) in the setter will fix it.

Comment: @Jason Thanks very much. Looks like a copy error on my part from tutorial i was following. Binding updates perfectly